# How to read a csv and create a list of maps out of each line?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a Java class to automate some behaviour on the web, my only problem is that now instead of the static data that I have I need to use the data from the csv.

for example:

this is one of the actions in my automation class:

```
WebElement supplierAddressField = driver.findElement(By.id("FieldaddressOfSupplierLine"));
        supplierAddressField.sendKeys("hollywood blvd 34");
```

So now, instead of the static "supplier address" value I want to iterate on each line of the `.sendKeys(csvLineMap.get("supplier address"));`

Because in each line I dont need all the headers info, this is why I think it will be the best to just create a list of maps, that each map key will be the header of the csv and the value will be the value for this header in a specific line.

this is the structure of the csv:

[image]

Please help me to figure this out...thanksss!!

Comment: I think it should be edited. The question is littered with WebDriver details although the question itself is about 'how to read csv and put values in a map'

Comment: if you will read the rest of the question you will see that it doesn't matter, I used some of the selenium code just so i can show exampel

Comment: So are you after java /selenium code to open a csv, and pick up the values and put them into arrays/maps?

Comment: @Louise i have all of ther selenium code, right now im only looking for the java code to parse my csv and create a list of maps so I can iterate between the csv lines and use its info

Answer (score 1):

## Apache Commons CSV

For what you are asking for I would recommend you look at [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).  One of the examples from their [User Guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) matches very closely with with the examples you are trying

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, this might be overly complex for what you want, but I always open csv's as excel files because then you can run down the columns.  The code for picking up any column would look like this:

```
                Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);                      
                Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
                nom = sheet.getRows();
                String[][] SheetArray = new String [2][nom];  
                   // change the first number to the number of columns you want, 
                   // or pick up the number same as you did with rows   


                Cell cell;           

                  // GETS DATA FROM SHEET AND RUNS THROUGH WHOLE LOOP BELOW FOR EACH REFERENCE            
                 for(int j =0;j<sheet.getRows();j++) // cycles through rows and loads into 2d array
                    { // start 6
                     cell = sheet.getCell(0, j); <- your column number here
                     cellcont = cell.getContents();                        
                      SheetArray[0][j] = cellcont;

                       // repeat the above block for each column you want

                        } // end 6
```

you now have a 2d array with all the info in it which you can handle however you want.

wrap the entire thing in a try .. catch.

Answer (score 0):

With [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) you can parse only the fields you are interested, in any order:

```
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    // Let's extract headers
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    parserSettings.selectFields("Field 5", "Field 1");

    //Rows will come organized according to your field selection
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll("path/to/file.csv");
```

If you prefer, you can easily get a map with the values of all columns:

```
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    // Let's extract headers
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    // To get the values of all columns, use a column processor
    ColumnProcessor rowProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

    //This will kick in our column processor
    parser.parse(new FileReader("path/to/file.csv"));

    //Finally, we can get the column values:
    Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = rowProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

Have a look. It is faster than any other parser and you can do much more, such as converting the values and generating java beans.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).